# New field in attribute table with automatic yes or no

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, intersection, expression

I have 2 different layers: one is `properties` and the other one is `park buffer`. I would like to add a field in the `properties` attribute table that says YES if "properties" and "buffer" intersects, and if they dont that it says NO; with possibility to later add if it intersects with 2 different layers.

I have tried with:

`if 'properties' overlay_contains 'buffer' then 'yes' else 'no'` - but this gave me an invalid expression

i have also tried with:
`if 'array_to_string(overlay_within('properties', buffer))' then 'yes' else 'no'`  - but still not working. I'm not super good with programming and I'm quite new to QGIS but eager to learn. Does anyone know if this is possible? if yes... how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you at least had a look at the tooltip the field calculator provides for the `if()` expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression to use is much easier: `overlay_intersects ('park buffer')`. It return true/false. If you set field type to integer, you get values of 0/1.

---

**Alternatives**

Syntax for `if()`-funtion with output (as string): yes/no:

```
if (overlay_intersects ('park buffer'), 'yes', 'no')
```

Alternatively, with same result, using `case` statement:

```
case when overlay_intersects ('park buffer') then 'yes' else 'no' end
```